# Using a file list to apply a script over a set of similarly named files (unix)

Tags: shell-script, scripting, bioinformatics

I have a set of files that are named like this:

```
NAM11_BW415_R1.fastq.gz         NAM13_BW968_R2.fastq.gz     NAM17_AC_Barrie_R1.fastq.gz  NAM3_PI648600_R2.fastq.gz  NAM7_Glenlea_R1.fastq.gz   PI648598_R2.fastq.gz
NAM11_BW415_R2.fastq.gz         NAM13_Frontana_R1.fastq.gz  NAM17_AC_Barrie_R2.fastq.gz  NAM3_PI648842_R1.fastq.gz  NAM7_Glenlea_R2.fastq.gz   PI648611_R1.fastq.gz
NAM11_Reeder_R1.fastq.gz        NAM13_Frontana_R2.fastq.gz  NAM17_BW388_R1.fastq.gz      NAM3_PI648842_R2.fastq.gz  NAM7_Laura_R1.fastq.gz     PI648611_R2.fastq.gz
NAM11_Reeder_R2.fastq.gz        NAM14_BW874_R1.fastq.gz     NAM17_BW388_R2.fastq.gz      NAM4_PI613279_R1.fastq.gz  NAM7_Laura_R2.fastq.gz     PI648672_R1.fastq.gz
NAM11_Webill_R1.fastq.gz        NAM14_BW874_R2.fastq.gz     NAM17_RedFife_R1.fastq.gz    NAM4_PI613279_R2.fastq.gz  NAM7_Marquis_R1.fastq.gz   PI648672_R2.fastq.gz
NAM11_Webill_R2.fastq.gz        NAM14_Glenn_R1.fastq.gz     NAM17_RedFife_R2.fastq.gz    NAM4_PI613280_R1.fastq.gz  NAM7_Marquis_R2.fastq.gz   PI648724_R1.fastq.gz
NAM12_BW431_L002_R1.fastq.gz    NAM14_Glenn_R2.fastq.gz     NAM1_PI648517_R1.fastq.gz    NAM4_PI613280_R2.fastq.gz  NAM8_FL62R1_R1.fastq.gz    PI648724_R2.fastq.gz
NAM12_BW431_L002_R2.fastq.gz    NAM14_Unity_R1.fastq.gz     NAM1_PI648517_R2.fastq.gz    NAM4_PI648524_R1.fastq.gz  NAM8_FL62R1_R2.fastq.gz    PI648768_R1.fastq.gz
NAM12_BW431_L008_R1.fastq.gz    NAM14_Unity_R2.fastq.gz     NAM1_PI648519_R1.fastq.gz    NAM4_PI648524_R2.fastq.gz  NAM8_Muchmore_R1.fastq.gz  PI648768_R2.fastq.gz
```

I want to use a script that takes two arguments (R1 and R2) of each file and do it on batches of maybe 16 files/processes each. How can I do this because even though the files look like that I want to generalize this for any folders that might look similar or have sets of files that end on R1 and R2.

I expect to take the files in groups of two (same name) and send them to a script that will create a set of folders where they are located and in that set of folders a bunch of commands will be executed by the script

So far as for what the code that I had what it did was okay for the first file but then it started to do the same process in the same folder instead of doing it across differently made folders.

So what I then want for the code is to take two similarly named files and apply a set of scripts on them. It would be quite better on case we can also for example take 8 of them at a time and start the next batch once done.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do. Can you edit your question to clarify? Also include the code you've already written that isn't working how you want.